# Keras: How to load CNN pre-trained weights (freezing the net) to use them in LSTM?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, lstm, conv-neural-network

I have this cnn model:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Convolution2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(n_rows,n_cols,1)))
model.add(Convolution2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(1,3)))
model.add(Flatten())

model.add(Dense(1024, activation='relu')) #needed?
model.add(Dense(3)) #default linear activation
```

I can train it and obtain related weights.

After I want to load the weights up to Flatten (the dense part is not useful for the second stage) and pass the Flatten to an LSTM.

Of course, it is also suggested to use TimeDistributed on the CNN net.

How to do all this: load weights, take only CNN part, TimeDistribute it, and finally add LSTM?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `model.save_weights("filename.h5")` to save the weights, and `model.load_weights("filename.h5")` to load them back into the model.

Source: https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#savingloading-only-a-models-weights

Comment: OK this is the first part. But how to load the weights up to Flatten (the dense part is not useful for the second stage) TimeDistribute it, pass the Flatten and finally add LSTM?